# Django Channels with Angular 14 Frontend

Tags: django, asynchronous, socket.io, django-channels, angular14

is there a way to create a socket with django and a angular 14 frontend?
I've tried that with ngx-socket-io, but its not working so far.

Any ideas how to solve this issue? I need to "poll" status from multiple celery tasks, so it's not effective to call the backend n (n=quantity of tasks) every x seconds to get the latest status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're set to use Django & Django-Channels for your backend, then you can't use `ngx-socket-io` because channels [does not support](https://github.com/django/channels/issues/1038) Socket IO. What you can do is use WebSockets in your frontend which is what channels was made for:

> Channels is a project that takes Django and extends its abilities beyond HTTP - to handle WebSockets, chat protocols, IoT protocols, and more

I suggest reading this guide to help you create an abstraction layer for the WebSocket: [How to implement WebSockets in Angular Project](https://indepth.dev/tutorials/angular/how-to-implement-websockets-in-angular-project).

You might also want to consider migrating to Flask as it has a [package](https://flask-socketio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that supports Socket-IO.